# Where can i host my webapp which use mongodb as a backend server

Tags: mongodb, server, web-hosting, netlify, social-media-like

I have created a project with MERN stack and want to host it. But as i came to know that netlify.app hosting site doesnt support hosting for database related projects as my project includes mongodb as a backend.
It will be a great help if anyone can suggest where should i host my project which can support mongodb as a backend also. And also any methods to do it that will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS EC2 Linux instance, where you can keep your project and at the same time you can store your data. For the initial phase of your project, you can install MongoDB on the same machine.

Comment: Umm, AWS is hard for me as of now is there any other hosting site similar to firebase. As firebase is simplest way to do it, but i want some other option.